# How to reconcile old usernames after move to Office 365 from SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, people-picker, user

Any old people/group columns from lists and libraries copied from the old 2010 environment show the following in the new environment: `Domain\UserName` With red squiggles and the error message:  `No exact match was found. Click the item(s) that did not resolve for more options.`

How do I change `Domain\UserName` to `i:0#.f|membership|UserName@EmailDomain.com`?  I'm open to any solution, PowerShell/CSOM, Excel Copy Paste, or whatever else has worked for you guys.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: How was the data copied?

Comment: It was a form library.  I saved the library as a template and added to the Office 365 site.

Comment: Either of the solutions you proposed would work. Which one to implement depends on your coding skill, the number of items that need to be updated, and whether you anticipate ever having to do this again.

Comment: It turns out that I cannot use Quick Edit mode, I think it has to do with the fact that it is an InfoPath document but I'm not sure.  PowerShell/CSOM it is.  I was mostly hoping that someone had worked through this issue before and could provide some direction.

Comment: If you get a solution, post it here as an answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I gave up and did it manually.  Since the field was just a text field linked to a person/group picker in an InfoPath form, it was a bit more difficult than I hoped.  To do it manually, I just opened the XML files for the forms and deleted any instances of `DOMAIN\`.